# Shortest Way to Sort a List of Strings by Sum of Letters

Tags: sorting

Think of this like a code golfing challenge. How would you sort a list of strings by sum of letters, meaning A:1, B:2,... in python?

Whatever I can think of is too big of a code. My thought was to create a dictionary with the string and its sum.

Comment: with code..................Please make an attempt....

Comment: Try the big code, once people see an effort , they'll help big time. Also check out [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the shortest and definitely not the most performant, but a simple solution:

```
l = ['dosvn', 'ghsoshnj', 'svblkhsdb', 'qgvmla']
def f(a,b):
    return cmp(sum([ord(c) for c in a]), sum([ord(c) for c in b]))

l.sort(f)
```